# How can I pass variables to a script one line at a time in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, variables

I have a list of files and titles set out as below:

```
Title    file1.txt
Title2   file2.txt
Title3   file3.txt
```

How can I pass this to a script line by line, setting column 1 and 2 as separate variables. e.g.

send Title as $1 and file1.txt as $2 to my script.
then send Title2 as $1 and file2.txt as $2 to the same script.

I don't know if there is a simpler way to do this but any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Where do you have the list? In a file? In a variable? Coming through a pipe?

Comment: I have done it in a file. It seems to have taken out the new lines as i meant to write it on separate lines:
Title file1.txt <NEXT LINE>
Title2 file2.txt <NEXT LINE>
Title3 file3.txt

I only want one line sent to the script at a time though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the file line by line, use parameter expansion to extract the titles and file names.

```
while read -r title file ; do
    echo Title is "$title", file is "$file".
done < input.lst
```

If the titles can contain spaces, it gets a bit more complicated:

```
while read -r line ; do
    title=${line% *}     # Remove everything from the first space.
    title=${title%%+( )} # Remove trailing spaces.
    file=${line##* }     # Remove everything up to the last space.
    echo Title is "$title", file is "$file".
done < input.lst
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for i in "Title file1.txt" "Title2 file2.txt" "Title3 file3.txt"; do Title $i; done
```

This is effectively like doing:

```
$ for i in "a b" "c d" "e f"; do echo $i; done
a b
c d
e f
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try making other script that run your objetive script:

```
#! /bin/bash 

ls /path/where/files/stay >> try.txt

a=1
while [ $a -lt 7 ]
    do
        ./script $(sed "$a"'q;d' try.txt) $(sed "$(($a+1))q;d" try.txt)
        a=$(($a+2))
    done
```

This script would run your script taking variables that you like from a file.